# test methods are accessing the wrong table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have test methods that do things like:

```
Rating rating = new Rating();
rating.Description = "X";
bool result = RatingManager.Insert(rating);
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

as well as ones that do the same thing, but instead look like

```
tblRating newrow = new tblRating();
newrow.Id = -99;
newrow.Description = "X";
dc.tblRatings.Add(newrow);
int rowsaffected = dc.SaveChanges();
Assert.AreNotEqual(0, rowsaffected);
```

When I run *these*, they work perfectly fine. I have the same methods for a bunch of other SQL tables. However, precisely one of them--for my table tblOrder--is not working. Instead, it is telling me:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Order'.
```

I assume this means somewhere I put "Order" rather than "tblOrder". However, I can't find where. (I'm using Visual Studio 2019.)

If it matters, the `dc` in question is an EntityFramework `Entities` variable. Also, I couldn't find [dbo].anything mentioned in the Manager classes.

Comment: Make sure you are pointing to the right database. Don't assume, an easy way is to breakpoint the DBConext and confirm manually

Comment: @TheGeneral how do i do that....

Comment: You need to make sure that there is a table called 'dbo.Order' in your database, otherwise, you may look for the "order" table in the wrong database.